# How to upload a file using curl that creates a directory in server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, curl

I can upload a file using cURL command in the following way,

curl --upload-file file_name http://example.com/upload/

Web server is Apache. It has a directory "upload" already created.

But when I do the following it fails,

curl --upload-file file_name http://example.com/upload/subdirectory/

cURL reports the following error,

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /upload/subdirectory/file_name
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

My requirement is to let cURL create a directory with "subdirectory" under "upload" and copy the file "file_name".

I guess it is to do something in Apache config file. 
Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You're right you probably have some kind of Apache redirect setup - but even then you'rs going to still need some kind of php file to process your put request. That's not something curl can do on the client side.